# Class not Found org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to create a project using Rest Assured with TestNG, but I am running into an issue with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher` . Rather new to this, so any help is appreciated.

I am using Maven:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at Tests.GameTests.GameTest.testGameSchema(GameTest.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 41 more
```

[image: Maven Dependencies]

```
package Tests.GameTests;

import Tests.TestModel;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.cfg.ValidationConfiguration;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static com.github.fge.jsonschema.SchemaVersion.DRAFTV4;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.when;
import static io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath;

public class GameTest extends TestModel {

    @Test
    public void testGameSchema() {
        JsonSchemaFactory jsonSchemaFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.newBuilder().
            setValidationConfiguration(ValidationConfiguration.
            newBuilder().
            setDefaultVersion(DRAFTV4).freeze()).freeze();

        when().
            get("/games/114").
            then().
            assertThat().
            body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("game_schema.json").
                    using(jsonSchemaFactory));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your `testng` file also, i think there is the wrong, you have to give the class name as `org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher` instead of `org/hamcrest/TypeSafeMatcher`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could explicitly add hamcrest dependency in your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I've faced similar issues with hamcrest several times, and adding it explicitly always helped.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same error except that I'm using JUnit instead of TestNG. That doesn't help the original poster but I figured that there were others like me.

The accepted answer wasn't working for me but I found that putting the Rest Assured dependency before JUnit in my POM solved the problem (I had Rest Assured after JUnit):

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Other dependencies... -->
    <!-- Add dependency for Rest Assured (has to go before JUnit to work) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Other dependencies... -->
</dependencies>
```

Source: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted#maven--gradle-users

> Notes
>
> 1. **You should place rest-assured before the JUnit dependency declaration in your pom.xml / build.gradle in order to make sure that the correct version of Hamcrest is used.**
> 2. REST Assured includes JsonPath and XmlPath as transitive dependencies

(emphasis is mine)

Comment: Damn, that would have costed me days to find out. If ever. I might just have avoided it altogether. Great info. This should be an accepted answer. It should also be available on restassured.io. Cheers